# unable to receive Bluetooth disconnecting event in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am facing the issue in Bluetooth event specially disconnecting event is not receiving but rest of the events are receiving. Why does the disconnection event is miss?.

````
public class BTReciver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
    
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                //Device found
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Bluetooth ACTION_FOUND ");

            } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                //Device is now connected
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Bluetooth ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED ");

            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                //Done searching
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Bluetooth ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED ");

            } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
                //Device is about to disconnect
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Bluetooth REQUESTED disconnected ");

            } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                //Device has disconnected
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Bluetooth has been disconnected ");
            }

        
    }  

  <receiver android:name=".BTReciver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>```
````

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions set in your manifest as stated in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED?

Comment: I solved this issue  by using  BluetoothAdapter action instead of the  BluetoothDevice action

Comment: Great! Feel free to answer your own question so future user can find your answer better :)

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by using of BluetoothAdapter action instead of the BluetoothDevice action.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

     
            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                        BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
                switch (state) {
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                         Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: STATE_OFF");

                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: STATE_TURNING_OFF");
                         break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                         Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: STATE_ON");

                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: STATE_TURNING_ON");
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    
};

     
 IntentFilter flBluetooth= new IntentFilter();
        flBluetooth.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
         registerReceiver(mReceiver, flBluetooth);
```